# Identify non-linear trend to know when to use log transformation in ARIMA?

Tags: time-series, arima, data-transformation, logarithm

There are basically three often used approaches to make time series stable based on three difference scenarios: 1) first difference for linear trend; 2) log for non-linear trend; 3) log seasonal difference for seasonality.

anyone know how to identify if the data has a non linear trend? and is there a test that indicate that time series has non linear trend?

Comment: First difference for linear trend is not appropriate. This is known as overdifferencing and has some negative consequences. Linear trends are appropriately adjusted for by fitting and then subtracting a linear trend. Similarly, seasonal differencing is not appropriate unless there is a seasonal unit root. Otherwise you introduce the problem of overdifferencing.

Comment: oh thankyou so much for correction sir, but i want to know how to know if a time series has a linier trend so that we need to use a log-transform? @RichardHardy. because a lot of people use log-transform but i didn't understand when to use them.